# mongodb get nested data segment of a object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

my data structure is like :

```
{
    "_id": xxxxx
    "user": "username",
    "data": {
        "21-04-2020": {
            "Study": "1:00:12",
            "other": "2:00:23"
        },
        "22-04-2020": {
            "study": "1:23:11",
            "other": "3:33:22"
        },

    }
}
```

I want to write a query to get data of particular day(like only 22-04-2020)
I tried a query like :

```
 db.activity.find({'user':'username','data.22-04-2020':{$exists:true})
```

but it is giving me all documents data like

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ea80f4151f5b94b73ba0327"), "user" : "username", "data" : { "21-04-2020" : { "study" : "1:00:12", "other" : "2:00:23" }, "22-04-2020" : { "study" : "1:23:11", "other" : "3:33:22" }}}
```

but I want only small segment for the day 22-04-2020 like :

```
{ "study" : "1:23:11", "other" : "3:33:22" }
```

so how to get a data segment by using key value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to add to this query is [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/), to get only certain fields out of document :

```
db.collection.find({ "user": "username", "data.22-04-2020": { $exists: true } },
{ "data.22-04-2020": 1, _id: 0 })
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CsVx0fLj8dU)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `aggregate` method. First, you need to `match` and then use the `project` operator to get the desired output. Try the below code:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      user: "username",
      "data.22-04-2020": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      study: "data.22-04-2020.study",
      other: "data.22-04-2020.other",
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YHo1xkNE1kA)